# Avoid checkbox captions from wrapping in Windows Vista dialogs

Tags: delphi

For a software project I need to align two additional personalized checkboxes in a microsoft windows vista dialog. I learned about adding checkboxes using Visual-Components and Visualgroups on a CustomizeInterface in delphi.

My Question: What do I need to do with those checkboxes' captions in order to avoid them from wrapping?

1st solution (showing the checkboxes one next to each other):

```
Dialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialogCustomize, lCustomizeInterface);
if getCheckBox1Caption <> '' then
  lCustomizeInterface.AddCheckButton(DWORD(CheckBox1ID), pWideChar(getCheckBox1Caption), Checked1);
if getCheckBox2Caption <> '' then
  lCustomizeInterface.AddCheckButton(DWORD(CheckBox2ID), pWideChar(getCheckBox2Caption), Checked2);
```

[image: 1st solution]

2nd solution (showing the checkboxes one below the other):

```
Dialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialogCustomize, lCustomizeInterface);
lCustomizeInterface.StartVisualGroup(DWORD(1005), pWideChar('Test'));
if getCheckBox1Caption <> '' then
  lCustomizeInterface.AddCheckButton(DWORD(CheckBox1ID), pWideChar(getCheckBox1Caption), Checked1);
if getCheckBox2Caption <> '' then
  lCustomizeInterface.AddCheckButton(DWORD(CheckBox2ID), pWideChar(getCheckBox2Caption), Checked2);
lCustomizeInterface.EndVisualGroup;
```

[image: 2nd solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid them wrapping. The `IFileDialogCustomize` interface offers no functionality to control layout. The control does all of that.

The best you can do is to use a shorter caption if you wish to avoid wrapping onto multiple lines. Or add some extra spaces to avoid the rather nasty mid-word breaks. For instance if you use this text `'Generate expandable / collapsible Excel export'` then the outcome is:

[image]